# Submit form in angular 2+ with arrays in model

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-forms

How can i create a Model with arrays

My Response:

```
 {
    "mail": "test@tes.com",
    "password": "test",
    "field_user_terms_and_conditions": {
        "und": {
            "value": "1"
        }
    },
    "profile_main":{
        "field_your_name":{
            "und":{
                "0":{
                    "value":"test"
                }
            }
        },
        "field_type_of_diet":{
            "und":{
                "value":"vegan"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I need to create a model to send with submit form

My model:

```
export class UsuarioModel {

    mail: string;
    password: string;
    -- this is my problem field_user_terms_and_conditions: string;

}
```

My HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" class="form-checkbox check-style"
                                        [(ngModel)]="usuario.field_user_terms_and_conditions">
```

Finally return a error in response... if I put my response in Postman, works fine..

Any idea how I can do it?

example in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wnew3y

Thankssssss

Comment: Don't get your question entirely. Can you create a stackblitz for the same? Also did you mean this `export class UsuarioModel {
  mail: string;
  password: string;
  profile_main: {};
}` ?

Comment: Hey Nicholas, Thanks for your answer and sorry for my english, is not easy to explain my problem :P https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wnew3y here you have an example :)

Comment: hmm... do you actually want to dynamically create model from data ?

Comment: Yes, for example if you submit the form, in the console you can see "Object", and in "field_your_name" need something like "field_your_name": {"und"{"value":"test name"}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I not understood the way to do it... I've declarated my value in my model and then in my service, create my data so POST it.

Example in my service:

```
    const authData = {
      returnSecureToken: true,
            profile_main: {
                field_type_of_diet:{
                  und: {
                    value: usuario.type_of_diet
                  }
                }
            }, .........

    };
```

Thanks all for the patience, if I can help any user here for this post just tell me :)